# Github action fails for pandas package not found, even though installed dependencies

Tags: pandas, github, github-actions, workflow, modulenotfounderror

This is my workflow file publish.yml

```
name: Publish Python Package

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: '3.8'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install build
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        python -m pip install pandas
    - name: Debug installed packages
      run: |
        python -m pip freeze
    - name: Build package
      run: python -m build
    - name: Publish package
      uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@
      with:
        user: __token__
        password: ${{ secrets.PYPI_API_TOKEN }}
```

Every time I tried run actions, filed on **Build packages** step.

```
* Creating venv isolated environment...
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools >= 40.8.0, wheel)
* Getting build dependencies for sdist...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 287, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return hook(config_settings)
  File "/tmp/build-env-fq0_u9yg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 358, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
  File "/tmp/build-env-fq0_u9yg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-fq0_u9yg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
  File "/tmp/build-env-fq0_u9yg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
    exec(code, locals())
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/runner/work/gscraper/gscraper/gscraper/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/home/runner/work/gscraper/gscraper/gscraper/base.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .types import _KT, _VT, _PASS, ClassInstance, Arugments, Context, ContextMapper, TypeHint, LogLevel
  File "/home/runner/work/gscraper/gscraper/gscraper/types.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame, Series, isna
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

On **Install dependencies** step,
already I installed `pandas` from requirements.txt,
and I even explicitly installed it.

And on **Debug installed packages** step,
I can find `pandas==2.0.3` installed without problem.

What is reason for this Github action problem,
and how could I fix this?